# cross NODE_ENV does not work while running the server from dist folder

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I am running the node server after the application build, pointing to the dist folder using: `node dist/server/main.js`. The server points to production environment by default (I think that's what webpack does by default).

In order to make it reference the local environment I tried the 2 scripts below:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local ./node_modules/.bin/cross-env node 
dist/server/main.js"
```

and

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local node dist/server/main.js"
```

These does not work. Is there any way if my server could point to the local/ development environment instead of always pointing to production? Thanks!

Comment: Following.. Even I have similar problem! cross-env does not set the environment

Answer (score 0):

Your crossenv syntax looks wrong. It should probably be:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local node dist/server/main.js"
```

Comment: I corrected my scripts, had typo earlier, but this doesn't work.. I refered the npm cross-env and cross-spawn documentation to use it..

Comment: This should set NODE_ENV to local correctly. In your `main.js` you can now check if NODE_ENV is set to 'local' by checking `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Comment: It is not getting set correctly. In my main.ts file when I console. log(process.env.NODE_ENV) -> it prints production. There's no where I'm explicitly setting env to production as well!